# Is it possible to verify arbitrary interaction using Mockito in a compact way?

Tags: methods, mocking, call, mockito

It is easy to verify that specific interaction (specific method call) occurred on a mock object in Mockito, and there is `verifyZeroInteractions()` for checking that no interactions occurred at all. Suppose I'm testing an interface such as that of a logger, with methods such as `info()`, `warn()`, `error()` etc. In a specific scenario I know one of these methods should be called, but I don't really care which one. Is there a compact way to check that any interaction with the mock object occurred without the need of specifying which exactly method should be called? Or perhaps such a mechanism is not necessary because "the Mockito way" of testing this would be different from what I imagine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can externalise the creation of your logger object from the class under test, there's no reason why you can't write your own test implementation of the Log Interface that will record which methods were exercised and inject it as part of your test setup.

Mock libraries do a lot of good, but sometimes there are corner cases like you have found where they may not cover your needs.

If you write your own implementation for testing like this, and inject it into yourt test class under test, then you can assert on `getCount() > 0`

```
public class LoggerTestSupportImpl implements ILogger {

    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public void info(String message) {
        count++;    
    }

    @Override
    public void warn(String message) {
        count++;    
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I have been testing my class so far, I was just wondering if Mockito could spare me from writing the trivial implementations for all methods.

Comment: I'd say that you have been doing the sensible thing Michal. Mockito doesn't support this kind of testing. Your only choice is to go down the `ArgumentCaptor` route as mentioned by Kevin, but this leads to a lot of "noise" in your test classes.

Comment: Agreed it is a bit noisy, but most noise is localized to declarations and the Before method, and you could even add the Captor to class level declarations if it is to be used across multiple Test methods (not even needed if not accessing msgs).  The nice thing about using Mockito is that you have access to the full logging API already.  To do so in your example you have to expand the capabilities of your hand-rolled mock (capture/retrieve arbitrary # of messages logged, etc.)  But for simple needs your way seems simpler, cleaner, *and* reusable, so those are some pluses for your approach.

Comment: It's a pity there apparently isn't any shorthand notation for this solution. Does anyone have an idea why the Mockito API allows testing for "no interaction" but not for the negation, i.e. "any interaction"? If instead of a method which checks conditions and throws an exception depending on result (`verifyZeroInteractions()`) they made a boolean method that returned the status, I could write both `assertTrue(anyInteractions(mock))` and `assertFalse(anyInteractions(mock))`. I could try/catch `AssertionError` and check my condition this way, but that would be so crazy.

Comment: One could argue that unit tests should be able to determine which of the methods are to be called, and that attempting to test for "any" interaction is not a proper test. Are you not able to execute your specific scenario with a known level of logging enabled?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check that any interaction occurred with a mock object, you can use the `Mockito.mockingDetails()` method and check that the number of invocations is not zero. Of course you could also do more detailed assertions based on the mocking details, but I guess just checking for not zero answers your question.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class TestClass {

    @Mock
    private Logger logger;

    @InjectMocks
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void testMethod_shouldLogMultipleTimes() {
        service.testMethod();
        assertThat(Mockito.mockingDetails(logger).getInvocations().size()).isNotZero();
    }
}
```

The code example uses `assertj` to check that the number of invocations is not zero.

Answer (score 3):

With log4j, to test the logger I do the following setup:

```
@Mock private Appender log4jAppender;
private Logger logger;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    Logger root = Logger.getRootLogger();
    if (!root.getAllAppenders().hasMoreElements()) {
        // No appenders means log4j is not initialized!
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }
    logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClassWhichLogs.class);
    logger.addAppender(log4jAppender);
}
```

and then in my test I do the following:

```
verifyZeroInteractions(log4jAppender);
```

or

```
verify(log4jAppender).doAppend(any(LoggingEvent.class);
```

If you need to test the values logged, you can provide a captor instead:

```
ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> logCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(LoggingEvent.class);
verify(log4jAppender).doAppend(logCaptor.capture());
assertTrue(logCaptor.getValue().contains("my text to match");
```

While this doesn't necessarily answer the generalized question (I don't think what you're looking for exists), it may solve this specific problem for testing logging.